# jQuery Conflicts?

Tags: jquery, conflict

I am installing the following script in a JS file which contains many others for a Wordpress blog. Could anyone point me in the direction of some tools to check for conflicts as this script doesn't work when I place it in the site build. (It works fine by itself).

Thank you...

```
this.randomtip = function(){
    var length = $("#message li").length;
    var ran = Math.floor(Math.random()*length) + 1;
    $("#message li:nth-child(" + ran + ")").show();
};

$(document).ready(function(){   
    randomtip();
});
```

Comment: do you see any errors in console..?

Comment: Just checked:ReferenceError: randomtip is not defined
[Break On This Error]  

randomtip();

Comment: "this.randomtip", in what scope?

Comment: Beetroot - Not sure what you mean by this if I am honest. The script was ripped from another source so I am not sure. :-)

Comment: well, you are limiting the scope of randomtip function using this, make it global and it should work fine, something like suggested in answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
var randomtip = function() {
    // [...]
};

// OR

function() randomtip {
    // [...]
}

// OR

window.randomtip = function() {
    // [...]
};
```

Comment: Third one in this list has done the trick. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a conflict. It's just a question of scope.

If `randomtip` is within scope, then it can be called, for example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    function randomtip(){
        var length = $("#message li").length;
        var ran = Math.floor(Math.random()*length) + 1;
        $("#message li:nth-child(" + ran + ")").show();
    };
    randomtip();
});
```

or

```
var MYNAMESPACE = (function() {
    var randomtip = function(){
        var length = $("#message li").length;
        var ran = Math.floor(Math.random()*length) + 1;
        $("#message li:nth-child(" + ran + ")").show();
    }
    ...
    return {
        randomtip: randomtip,
        ...
    };
})();

$(document).ready(function(){   
    MYNAMESPACE.randomtip();
});
```